# How to run php function after js append

Tags: javascript, php

I append a value from my .js file like so

```
        elemscore.append("You Scored: " + score);
```

I then need to access database records based on the score. How can I achieve this after the append

Comment: and an ajax request ..

Comment: Make an AJAX request to a "page" (some PHP script which handles the request) on the server.  That server-side script would accept the value(s) it needs from the request (like any other PHP script would), perform whatever server-side logic you write, and respond with the data needed by the client-side code.  The client-side code would then use that data in the response handler for the AJAX request.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform an ajax request something like this.

```
var url = 'http://localhost/phalcon3/blog?month='+pmonth+'&

$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url: url
    data: {postVar1:"value",postVar2:"second value"},

    success: function(result){
        // either do something with whats returned or call another jquery function
        console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(){
         // error reporting/handling
    }
});
```